# Printing out list to console

Tags: c#, list, console

I am trying to output the whole list to console, but all I end up getting is the message "Stack overflow 19277 times". Can someone please help me out? I have now added the rest of the code. As you can see, the list wont print to console. I have tried many ways. The ideal solution would be a PrintAllEmployees-method to console under the company class.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Entities
{
    public class Person
    {
        private string name;
        private int age;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }
        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            name = Name;
            age = Age;

        }
    }

    public class Employee : Person
    {
        public string hireDate;

        public Employee(string name, int age, string hireDate) : base(name, age)
        {
            hireDate = HireDate;
        }

        public string HireDate
        {
            get { return hireDate; }
            set { hireDate = value; }
        }

    }

   public class Company
    {
        public List<Person> employeesList = new List<Person>();

        
        public string companyName
        {
            get { return companyName; }
            set { companyName = value; }
        }

        public int employeeCount
        {
            get { return employeeCount; }
            set { employeeCount = value; }
        }

        public Company(string CompanyName, int EmployeeCount)
        {
            EmployeeCount = employeeCount;
            CompanyName = companyName;
        }
        
       
    }
}


    using Entities;


namespace Checkpoint_2___Console_App
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Person> employeesList = new List<Person>();

            Person myPerson = new("Kari", 35);
            Employee myEmployee = new("Ole", 35, "10.10.2000");
            Company myCompany = new("Baker Hansen", 15);


            employeesList.Add(myPerson);
            employeesList.Add(myEmployee);

          
            


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the `ToString` method of `Person` (and `Employee` if different).

Comment: I dont have a ToString-method. How do i show that?

Comment: If you remove the `Console.WriteLine` do you still get the error? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: We need a [mcve] because building code based on what you have shown [works fine](https://rextester.com/VYNQ25522). Even [overriding ToString](https://rextester.com/WOCSS31460) doesn't produce any problems. I'm sure you appreciate why we need a [mcve] since we need to be able to reproduce your issue to help you, and if we can't do that, we can't help you.

Comment: You say you don't have a `ToString` method, so perhaps the constructor of `Person`, `Employee`, or `Company` is causing this issue. My initial assumption was that you were perhaps calling `this.ToString()` in `Employee` resulting in an infinite loop, but evidently this isn't the case.

Comment: The Company class has invalid properties causing stackoverflow exception. if you compare this to Employee class.. you have private fields in Employee class wrapped inside properties. While you don't have any private fields in Company class.

Comment: After editing the code does not compile.

Comment: You need to use correct casing among property names, method argument names etc.

Comment: What does that mean? Im just getting into coding, would you explain a little more in depth? @Chetan

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties

Comment: both constructors assign the class variables to the parameters inserted into the constructor. This should be reversed. The parameters live only locally inside the constructor. Normally one passes values as parameters into the constructor so that the class properties will receive them.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code:

```cs
public string companyName
{
    get { return companyName; }
    ...
```

It says, "If you want to know the company name, you need to know the company name". That leads to stack overflow, because it keeps looping.

I guess what you meant was:

```cs
public string CompanyName
{
    get { return companyName; }
    ...
```

Convention is that property names start with uppercase, private members with lower case.

The same goes for employeeCount.

Comment: It will solve the problem, according to [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#camel-case) private fields start with `_` or `s_` for static fields. Sorry for being petty

Comment: @sschwei1: Thanks for pointing that out. I googled around and found this link https://web.archive.org/web/20100316191542/http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/articles/361363.aspx among others. It looks like Microsoft over the years went from "don't prefix private members with underscore", over "you can prefix private members with underscore" to "you should prefix private members with underscore". When I worked at Microsoft 15 years ago, we didn't use the prefix.